# Reading a specific column of a text file into a list (python 3.6.3)

Tags: python

I know there's a million questions on this but I couldn't find one that matches what I'm looking for. Let's say I have a text file like this:

```
1    34
2    65
3    106
```

And I want to scan this file and read only the second column such that `data=[34 65 106]`, how might I go about this? Further, if I wanted to make this program able to read any length dataset and any specific column input by the user. I can do most things in simple python but reading files eludes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Sound like the case for a small helper function:

```
def read_col(fname, col=1, convert=int, sep=None):
    """Read text files with columns separated by `sep`.

    fname - file name
    col - index of column to read
    convert - function to convert column entry with
    sep - column separator
    If sep is not specified or is None, any
    whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are
    removed from the result.
    """
    with open(fname) as fobj:
         return [convert(line.split(sep=sep)[col]) for line in fobj]

res = read_col('mydata.txt')
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[34, 65, 106]
```

If you want the first column, i.e. at index `0`:

```
read_col('mydata.txt', col=0)
```

If you want them to be floats:

```
read_col('mydata.txt', col=0, convert=float)
```

If the columns are separated by commas:

```
read_col('mydata.txt', sep=',')
```

You can use any combination of these optional arguments.

### Explanation

We define a new function with default parameters:

```
def read_col(fname, col=1, convert=int, sep=None):
```

This means you have to supply the file `fname`. All other arguments are optional and the default values will be used if not provide when calling the function.

In the function, we open the file with:

```
with open(fname) as fobj:
```

Now `fobj` is an open file object. The file will be closed when we de-dent, i.e. here when we end the function.

This:

```
[convert(line.split(sep=sep)[col]) for line in fobj]
```

creates a list by going through all lines of the file. Each line is split at the separator `sep`. We take only the value for the column with index `col`. We also convert the value in the datatype of `convert`, i.e. into an integer per default.

## Edit

You can also skip the first line in the file:

```
with open(fname) as fobj:
     next(fobj)
     return [convert(line.split(sep=sep)[col]) for line in fobj]
```

Or more sophisticated as optional argument:

```
def read_col(fname, col=1, convert=int, sep=None, skip_lines=0):
    # skip first `skip_lines` lines
    for _ in range(skip_lines):
        next(fobj)
    with open(fname) as fobj:
         return [convert(line.split(sep=sep)[col]) for line in fobj]
```

Comment: I like this one, however in your example, what is the name of the resultant list? Is it just 'mydata.txt'?

Comment: You can give it any name. Just right he name left of the `=` at  the function call. Modified my answer accordingly,

Comment: much appreciated, one last question, say my data has a title, meaning I need to pass over the first line without reading it to avoid the type error, how might I go about that?

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem. Just click on the check mark ('✓') next to the answer. This will toggle it from grayed-out to filled-in.

Answer (score 3):

`pandas` is a useful library for tasks such as this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None, delimiter=r"\s+")
lst = df.iloc[:, 1].tolist()
```

Comment: Will this give new a list of floats? Sorry for the simple questions, I've only had about 3 hrs of formal python training

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure. It will be either float or int. Try this to find out which: `print(df.dtypes)`

Answer (score 1):

You an use a list comprehension:

```
data = [b for a, b in [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('filename.txt')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to get list of all lines via 
    fileobj.readlines()
Then you can run a for loop to iterate through the lines one by one , for each line you can split it by char (" ")
Then in the same for loop you can add the second index of split result to a existing list which will be your final result

```
a=fil.readlines()
t=[]
for f in a:
    e=f.split(" ")
    t.append(e[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file delimited?

You'll want to first open the file:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
   filedata = f.readlines()
```

Create a list, loop through the lines and split each line into a list based on your delimiter, and then append the indexed item in the list to your original list.

```
data = []
for line in filedata:
    columns = line.split('*your delimiter*')
    data.append(columns[1])
```

Then the data list should contain what you want.